# Quarkus with Embedded Hazlecast fails on AWS with error "Failed to configure discovery strategy"

Tags: java, quarkus

I am trying to deploy a quarkus 1.12.1.Final application with an embedded hazlecast cache (4.1) on AWS ECS Fargate. The embedded cache works fine on local but when configured and deployed to AWS gives error "Failed to configure discovery strategy"

I followed this link for setting up on AWS :https://hazelcast.com/blog/how-to-set-up-hazelcast-imdg-on-aws-ecs/

Has anyone been able to successfully setup an embedded cache like this on AWS? Any help is appreciated. The stacktrace is below.

```
2021-09-28T10:51:19.518+02:00 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to configure discovery strategies
2021-09-28T10:51:19.518+02:00 at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.loadDiscoveryStrategies(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:161)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.518+02:00 at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.<init>(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:58) 
2021-09-28T10:51:19.519+02:00 at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryServiceProvider.newDiscoveryService(DefaultDiscoveryServiceProvider.java:29)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.520+02:00 at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node.createDiscoveryService(Node.java:341)

2021-09-28T10:51:19.520+02:00 at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.Node.<init>(Node.java:267)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.520+02:00 at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceImpl.createNode(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:148)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.520+02:00 at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:117)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.520+02:00 at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:211)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.520+02:00 at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:190)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.520+02:00 at com.hazelcast.instance.impl.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:128)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.521+02:00 at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:57)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.521+02:00 at org.GreetingApplication.create(GreetingApplication.java:58)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.521+02:00 at org.GreetingApplication.init(GreetingApplication.java:32)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.521+02:00 at org.GreetingApplication_Bean.create(GreetingApplication_Bean.zig:700)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.521+02:00 at org.GreetingApplication_Bean.create(GreetingApplication_Bean.zig:716)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.521+02:00 at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:96)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.521+02:00 at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.access$000(AbstractSharedContext.java:14)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.521+02:00 at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:29)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.522+02:00 at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.522+02:00 at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.522+02:00 at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.522+02:00 at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.522+02:00 at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getApplicationScopedDelegate(ClientProxies.java:17)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.522+02:00 at org.GreetingApplication_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(GreetingApplication_ClientProxy.zig:67)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.522+02:00 at org.GreetingApplication_ClientProxy.arc_contextualInstance(GreetingApplication_ClientProxy.zig:82)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.523+02:00 at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ClientProxyUnwrapper.apply(ClientProxyUnwrapper.java:11)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.523+02:00 at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.runtime.ResteasyInjectorFactoryRecorder$1.apply(ResteasyInjectorFactoryRecorder.java:22)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.523+02:00 at io.quarkus.resteasy.common.runtime.QuarkusInjectorFactory$UnwrappingPropertyInjector.inject(QuarkusInjectorFactory.java:65)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.523+02:00 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.createApplication(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:423)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.523+02:00 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.initializeObjects(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:266)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.523+02:00 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.startInternal(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:138)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.524+02:00 at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResteasyDeploymentImpl.start(ResteasyDeploymentImpl.java:122)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.525+02:00 at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.ResteasyStandaloneRecorder.staticInit(ResteasyStandaloneRecorder.java:35)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.525+02:00 at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit-210558872.deploy_0(ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit-210558872.zig:906)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.525+02:00 at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit-210558872.deploy(ResteasyStandaloneBuildStep$staticInit-210558872.zig:40)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.525+02:00 at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:169)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.525+02:00 ... 9 more
2021-09-28T10:51:19.526+02:00 Caused by: com.hazelcast.aws.RestClientException: Failure in executing REST call
2021-09-28T10:51:19.526+02:00 at com.hazelcast.aws.RestClient.call(RestClient.java:114)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.526+02:00 at com.hazelcast.aws.RestClient.lambda$callWithRetries$0(RestClient.java:84)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.526+02:00 at com.hazelcast.aws.RetryUtils.retry(RetryUtils.java:50)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.526+02:00 at com.hazelcast.aws.RestClient.callWithRetries(RestClient.java:84)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.527+02:00 at com.hazelcast.aws.RestClient.get(RestClient.java:76)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.527+02:00 at com.hazelcast.aws.AwsMetadataApi.metadataEcs(AwsMetadataApi.java:92)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.527+02:00 at com.hazelcast.aws.AwsClientConfigurator.resolveCluster(AwsClientConfigurator.java:143)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.527+02:00 at com.hazelcast.aws.AwsClientConfigurator.createAwsClient(AwsClientConfigurator.java:65)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.527+02:00 at com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategy.<init>(AwsDiscoveryStrategy.java:79)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.527+02:00 at com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategyFactory.newDiscoveryStrategy(AwsDiscoveryStrategyFactory.java:50)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.527+02:00 at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.buildDiscoveryStrategy(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:195)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.529+02:00 at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.loadDiscoveryStrategies(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:141)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.529+02:00 ... 44 more
2021-09-28T10:51:19.529+02:00 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
2021-09-28T10:51:19.529+02:00 at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.530+02:00 at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.530+02:00 at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.530+02:00 at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.530+02:00 at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.530+02:00 at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:292)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.530+02:00 at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.530+02:00 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:754)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.530+02:00 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
2021-09-28T10:51:19.531+02:00 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
```

EDIT
I used maven quarkus quick start to create a simple project to test again (Its a different quarkus version but error is same)

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.11.7.Final:create -DprojectGroupId=org.acme -DprojectArtifactId=getting-started -DclassName="org.acme.getting.started.GreetingResource" -Dpath="/hello"
```

Added additional dependency for hazlecast:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
<artifactId>hazelcast-all</artifactId>
<version>4.1</version>
```

Added a simple Application class to it to init the cache on startup as per example here: https://hazelcast.com/blog/how-to-set-up-hazelcast-imdg-on-aws-ecs/

```
    config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(true);
config.getNetworkConfig().getInterfaces().setEnabled(true).addInterface("10.0.*.*");
```

Comment: Well discovery strategy its important, but have you checked the read timeout that appears to be the root of the issue ?

Comment: Also provide more information about your dependency set or a minimal reproducer example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, if you want to bring more audience into this topic with the information provided a lot of different things ca be causing the issue

Comment: @JavierToja, thanks for the quick response. Yes I noticed the timeout and even tried to increase it and still no success. Instead of Quarkus, when I followed the official guide using a springboot app (https://github.com/hazelcast-guides/ecs-embedded) it worked perfectly. I used the same IAM roles (Task and execution) and Security groups as used for my quarkus service to check if that was the issue. With springboot its able to discover other instnaces and form a cluster.

Comment: @JavierToja, I have edited the post with more info as you requested.

Comment: Can you try with the hazzlecast quarkus dependency from this guid https://guides.hazelcast.org/hazelcast-client-quarkus/, if it works i will redact the anwser @xge2

Comment: @JavierToja, on adding just the quarkus-hazlecast-client getting following error:  
Caused by: com.hazelcast.config.InvalidConfigurationException: Invalid configuration
---
Caused by: com.hazelcast.config.properties.ValidationException: There is no discovery strategy factory to create 'DiscoveryStrategyConfig{properties={connection-timeout-seconds=20, read-timeout-seconds=20}, className='com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategy', discoveryStrategyFactory=null}' Is it a typo in a strategy classname? Perhaps you forgot to include implementation on a classpath?

Comment: @JavierToja when I added additionally the com.hazelcas:hazelcast-aws 3.4 dependency, started getting the old timeout error again.

Comment: I cannot test myself the project, I don't think that is a type, for what I can see you have different configuration options, I'm not 100% sure that you need the aws dependency, but if you add this dependency check for dependency conflicts. IMYO, the whole issue should come due to the place where your configuration are pointing, and the cause of the read timeout. If you can enable tracing or increase the log level to try to test where it is trying to connect, maybe its pointing to some default uri instead

Comment: @JavierToja, Thanks to your earlier pointer on time out. On further comparison, I noticed that base docker images used for springboot and quarkus were different. On further comparison, the quarkus base image had proxy enabled and for NO_PROXY some AWS related IPs where missing. Once I updated it to the below, it started working:  ENV NO_PROXY='169.254.169.254,localhost,127.0.0.1,.amazonaws.com,169.254.170.2,\\.\pipe\docker_engine'   Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: You are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

On further comparison, I noticed that base docker images used for springboot and quarkus were different. On comparison, the quarkus base image had proxy enabled and for NO_PROXY some AWS related IPs where missing. Once I updated it to the below, it started working:

```
ENV NO_PROXY='169.254.169.254,localhost,127.0.0.1,.amazonaws.com,169.254.170.2,\\.\pipe\docker_engine'
```